# Creating a List of Event Counts

Tags: list, threshold

I am trying to loop through my data and for every time a threshold is exceeded, i want to rasie a flag and count it. At the end i want an output of a data frame having those rows that were flagged and their corresponding information

I have gotten this far..

```
frame_of_reference = frame_of_reference.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
window_size = 10
for i in range(1, len(frame_of_reference['Number_of_frames']), window_size):
        events_ttc =  [1 if 0.0 < frame_of_reference['TTC_radar'].any() <= 1.5 else 0]
events_ttc
```

but instead of giving me a dataframe, it only gives me a one or a zero.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Where is `i` being used inside the loop ? You want to loop through the entire series `window_size` times ?

Comment: Yes please. And extract 'events' that violate the threshold.